# Save page of WebKitWebView into file

Tags: c++, c, webkit, webkitgtk, webkit2

I have this *almost* solved. I've found this function:

```
void
webkit_web_view_save_to_file (WebKitWebView *web_view,
                              GFile *file,
                              WebKitSaveMode save_mode,
                              GCancellable *cancellable,
                              GAsyncReadyCallback callback,
                              gpointer user_data);
```

in the [WebKitGTK official documentation](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitWebView.html)

In my project I use it like this:

```
webkit_web_view_save_to_file( WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webview), g_file_new_for_path("/absolute/path/to/file"), WEBKIT_SAVE_MODE_MHTML, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

However, it does absolutely nothing (There's no file where it should be - maybe I'm missing something?). I've even put it inside a `while(true)` loop (With a `sleep(10)` after the `webkit_web_view_save_to_file()`).

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the process is asynchronous, so I had to write another function that got the result.

The function:

```
static void webkit_result (GObject      *source_object,
                GAsyncResult *res,
                gpointer      user_data)
{
    gboolean success = FALSE;

    success = webkit_web_view_save_to_file_finish(WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(source_object), res, NULL);

    if (success)
        printf("Hurray!\n");
    else
        printf("Uh oh!\n");

    /* ... */

}
```

And then the corrected line of code:

```
  webkit_web_view_save_to_file(WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webview),  g_file_new_for_path("/absolute/path/to/file"), WEBKIT_SAVE_MODE_MHTML, NULL, webkit_result, NULL);
```